# How to delete all files expect specific file type in the folder using command line

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, command

I have lot of files in specific folder.

I want to delete all files expect *.html file type in that folder.

Is there any way to do this in command line? I am using Linux.

Comment: please add your operation system (windows, mac, linux etc).

Comment: This question also better fits to http://superuser.com/

Comment: linux operating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that you refer to linux command line, please update your question if not.

```
find ./folder/to/look/in -not -iname '*.html' -exec rm {} \;
```

[Here's an explanation of what this does](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.%2Ffolder%2Fto%2Flook%2Fin+-not+-iname+%27%2a.html%27+-exec+rm+%7B%7D+%5C%3B+)

**edit**

If you have not too many files then you might want to make `find` execute one single `rm` command. You can do that with using `+` instead of `;`

```
find ./folder/to/look/in -not -iname '*.html' -exec rm {} +
```

[Here's an explanation of this one](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.%2Ffolder%2Fto%2Flook%2Fin+-not+-iname+%27%2a.html%27+-exec+rm+%7B%7D+%2B)

Comment: I like your solution, but not as much as I like pipelines.

Comment: Even though it's not an expensive resource I find it a bit wasteful to start an extra program and create a pipe if it's not necessary

Comment: I actually didn't know about -exec. Your answer is more correct than mine because mine does something totally pointless. I've just added the explainshell link to your answer and I'm deleting mine.